# How to render a loader until data is fetched in React Native

Tags: javascript, android-asynctask, react-native, jsx

I am fetching data through an async request. I know that I need to wait for the api request to complete before displaying the data. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to create a loader to wait for the data to load.I am new to react, so if I could also get help with implementing it as well, that would be fantastic! Here is my current code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ListView, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight} from 'react- native';
import Header from '../Components/Header';
import Api from '../Utility/Api';


export default class CalendarPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
}

async componentWillMount() { this.setState(
    {data: await Api.getDates()},

    )
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Header pageName="Calendar" navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
        <View style = {{flex:9}}>
            <View>
              { this.state.data.days[0].items.map((item) => (
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.summary}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.start.dateTime}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
            </View>
         </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

}

Comment: I think you can do two returns so if there is no state, then return a loader otherwise return the data loader. And I don't think you've set up your initial state yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple example using `ActivityIndicator` -

import `ActivityIndicator`

```
import { View, Text, ListView, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, ActivityIndicator} from 'react- native';
```

set `data` state to null

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }
```

do conditional rendering

```
  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return (
        <ActivityIndicator
          animating={true}
          style={styles.indicator}
          size="large"
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Header pageName="Calendar" navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
        ....
        ....
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

indicator style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  indicator: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 80
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although solution proposed by @vinayr works fine but user will still be able to click on screen and perform some action even while loader is being shown which can lead to crash.

One solution is wrap loader inside a Modal.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Modal,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: '#00000040',
  },
  activityIndicatorHolder: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
});


const SmartLoader = (props) => {
  const {
    isLoading,
    ...attributes
  } = props;

  return (
    <Modal
      transparent
      animationType={'none'}
      visible={isLoading}
      onRequestClose={() => { console.log('Noop'); }}
    >
      <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
        <View style={styles.activityIndicatorHolder}>
          <ActivityIndicator
            animating={isLoading}
            size="large"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default SmartLoader;
```

After that you can use it anywhere in your component, user will not be able to perform any action till loader is finished ( made hidden based on flag)

Comment: how to show/hide the modal qhen a button is cliked?